# how do I share a single socket between the producer and consumer?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, thread-safety, executorservice

How do I ensure that the `Producer` and `Consumer` each use the same socket to communicate with the server?  Or, perhaps, another class should handle the socket connection?  The producer and consumer are **both** on the **client**.

It seems that the socket connection is tied into the `Producer` and `Consumer` in such a way that they cannot, seemingly, be untangled, so, while I would like to put the connection into a third class, I do not see how to do so.

I very much like this pattern of `Producer` and `Consumer`, only I don't know how to implment it within the constraints of the **client** code so that all socket communication with the server goes through a single socket.

I suppose it might be possible to send/retrieve a unique identifier, but that would make the server overly complex.

code:

```
package net.bounceme.dur.client;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import net.bounceme.dur.data.State;
import net.bounceme.dur.data.Title;

public class Producer implements Runnable {

    private final BlockingQueue<Title> queue;
    private final String server = "localhost";
    private final int portNumber = 8080;

    public Producer(BlockingQueue<Title> q) {
        this.queue = q;
    }

    private Title connect() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        Socket socket = new Socket(server, portNumber);
        Title title = null;
        State state = State.undefined;
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        title = (Title) objectInputStream.readObject();
        return title;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            connect();
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Producer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            //exit?
        }
    }
}
```

consumer:
    package net.bounceme.dur.client;

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import net.bounceme.dur.data.State;
import net.bounceme.dur.data.Title;

public class Consumer implements Runnable {

    private final BlockingQueue<Title> queue;
    private final String server = "localhost";
    private final int portNumber = 8080;

    public Consumer(BlockingQueue<Title> q) {
        this.queue = q;
    }

    private void consume() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
        Socket socket = new Socket(server, portNumber);
        Title title = queue.take();
        title.setState(State.x);
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(title);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            consume();
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException | InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Consumer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            //exit?
        }

    }
}
```

Adapted from:

http://www.journaldev.com/1034/java-blockingqueue-example-implementing-producer-consumer-problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a single `Socket` and share the `InputStream` and `OutputStream`, one to each (depending on which one is reading and which one is writing to the server).

Your `consume()` method shouldn't initialize anything either, it should have everything ready so it can read data and process it. Your example code shows the method actually creating a new `Socket` and a new `ObjectOutputStream`, when they should be created only once.

```
Socket s = new Socket(server, port);
InputStream in = s.getInputStream();
OutputStream out = s.getOutputStream();

consumer.setStream(in);     // Or vice-versa
producer.setStream(out);    // You can also provide it as a constructor argument
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't realize it was possible to pass around sockets like that, I assumed that it would create an error.